# rails 5.2.0 `method_missing': undefined method `has_one_attached'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Meu projeto usa Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.4.1p111.
rails 5.2 vem com active_record "pré instalado", rodei o `rails active_storage:install` que gerou os migrations, depois `rails db:migrate` tudo certinho, no model Category.rb coloquei `has_one_attached :image`.

Porem o has_one_attached não é reconhecido.

No meu config/application.rb tenho `require 'rails/all'` que importa o active_record junto.

config/storage.yml está assim

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>
local:
   service: Disk
   root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia de o que possa ser?

Esse é o erro que me retorna:

```
/Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `has_one_attached' for Category (call 'Category.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/carlos/Downloads/mysalon/app/models/category.rb:4:in `<class:Category>'
    from /Users/carlos/Downloads/mysalon/app/models/category.rb:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:100:in `load'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:100:in `load'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:653:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:467:in `load_file'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:365:in `block in require_or_load'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:43:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:193:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/carlos/Downloads/mysalon/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:249:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rails_admin-1.3.0/lib/rails_admin.rb:32:in `config'
    from /Users/carlos/Downloads/mysalon/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `block in load'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `load'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/carlos/Downloads/mysalon/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require_relative'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:in `new'
    from config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/Downloads/mysalon/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlos/Downloads/mysalon/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/Downloads/mysalon/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema: Active Storage + rails_admin. Após muita pesquisa e pouco sucesso, resolvi criar um defeito no GitHub: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/3025 Ainda sem resposta, vamos acompanhar.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer utilizar o Active Storage, o comando correto é:

```
rails active_storage:install
```

No lugar do comando:

```
rails active_record:install
```

Comment: Foi só um erro de digitação ao escrever a pergunta... se ler a minha pergunta, eu digo que gerou os migrations normalmente.
Então o erro não é esse. Estou achando que a gen rails_admin que entra em conflito com ele.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Esta é uma aplicação nova ou você migrou para Rails 5.2?

Comment: novinha em folha, até recriei e testei antes de instalar a gem rails_admin, e funciona. E no Git desta gem tem uma inssue falando sobre isso: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2990